# Tar: How to ignore the archive itself

Tags: backup, unix, tar

I was planning to do a quick backup of my website. So I tried to run the following command in my webroot:

```
tar cvfz backup.tar.gz .
```

That seemed to be working nicely for a while. Until I discovered it had started to backup `backup.tar.gz`...

Is there an easy way that I can get it to ignore the file I am archiving *to*?

***Note:*** I would of course have put the archive file in the directory above it if I could. But I only have access to my home directory.

Comment: What about access to /tmp? That's always been world writable on every machine I've ever touched.

Comment: That could be. But that is also readable by everyone, isn't it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

```
tar cvfz backup.tar.gz *
```

This way shell extends the *, vs the tar reading current directory. The difference is that the produced archive does not contain root folder.

If you also need to include hidden files (.files) you can try

```
tar cvfz backup.tar.gz * .??*
```

This includes .files and prevents inclusion of parent directories.

Comment: Interesting. What does `.??*` do exactly?

Comment: ? is a 'any character' when the * is 'any character sequence'. Shell does not normally include .files with *, so .?? is simply any file beginning with a dot and having two or more characters after the dot, thus preventing inclusion of . and ..

Comment: .??* of course has a problem, it does not include .a and so on, but it is faster to write than .[^.]* and files with a dot and one character are rare.

Comment: Ahaa. Good stuff. Seems to be working nicely :)

Comment: To expand on this a bit, add a `./` before the *. This makes it possible to add --exclude statements that are relative to the root path of the tar command.


`tar cvfz backup.tar.gz ./* --exclude "./relative/path"`

Answer (score 7):

`b=backup.tar.gz; tar --exclude=$b -zcf $b .`

Comment: A little explanation of what's going on here and how your answer differs from the others already offered will greatly improve this answer.

Comment: That does not work when you create the file the first time (tested with tar 1.3 on both Debian and Ubuntu). So do: b=backup.tar.gz; touch $b; tar --exclude=$b -zcf $b .

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there's a nicer way, but I always just do it from the a different directory.

```
tar cvfz backup.tar.gz /path/to/www
```

This [link](http://linuxdevcenter.com/pub/a/linux/lpt/20_08.html) looks like it has the information you might want.

Comment: Yeah, but I can't do that since that directory is the only one I have access to. Added note about that to my question :)

Comment: the `--exclude=` option looks viable, as well.